# ES6 Import Folder

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, es6-module-loader

Does the ES6 module syntax allow you to import something from a folder?

For example if I have `./sub/main.js` and I try `import foo from './sub` in the `./main.js` file, will this work?

Could I get this sort of importing from a folder to work with babel and webpack?

Basically this would be the equivalent of `__init__.py` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6's module syntax does not dictate how the module identifier should be interpreted.

That solely depends on the module loader / bundler you are using, which seems to be webpack. Not sure how easily it can be implemented, have a look at the [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html#resolve-dependencies).